# Extra space inserted when logging QString with easylogging++

Tags: c++, qt, logging, format, easylogging++

I have multiple lines of code where the logger is triggered (INFO mode):

```
LOG(INFO) << connectionsBOther.at(connectionIdx).line
          << " (" << QString::number(connectionsBOther.at(connectionIdx).direction) << ") | "
          << connectionsBOther.at(connectionIdx).directionTarget
          << " "
          << QString::number(connectionsBOther.at(connectionIdx).departureRelative);
```

An example for the output can be seen below:

```
2017-11-29 14:38:07,643 INFO  [default] M85 ( 2) |  Hello  1
```

The issue I'm having is the extra space that seems to be appended IN FRONT of the respective `QString::number()` call (spaces below are marked with # to mke them more visible):

```
2017-11-29 14:38:07,643 INFO  [default] M85#(#2)#|##Hello##1
```

I'm looking for the following output:

```
2017-11-29 14:38:07,643 INFO  [default] M85#(2)#|#Hello#1
```

I need to use INFO for this output. I'm used to `LOG(DEBUG)` putting extra spaces all over the place but wasn't expecting this for the `LOG(INFO)`.

Comment: please try 1-cout << QString::number(2)  2-cout << Qstring("2") 3-LOG(INFO) << "2" 4-LOG(INFO) << QString::number(2) 5-LOG(INFO) << QString("2")  just to make sure that the problem is specific to your case

Comment: See @p-a-o-l-o 's answer as well as my comment below his. The issue is strictly related to the logging mechanisms of easylogging++ from what I know so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: https://github.com/muflihun/easyloggingpp/issues/179, a `LoggingFlag::AutoSpacing` flag is available.

From documentation (at https://github.com/muflihun/easyloggingpp#logging-flags):

> You can set/unset these flags by using static el::Loggers::addFlag and
>   el::Loggers::removeFlag. You can check to see if certain flag is
>   available by using el::Loggers::hasFlag, all these functions take
>   strongly-typed enum el::LoggingFlag

I think you should unset the above mentioned flag to avoid automatic spacing (i.e. to remove extra spaces from your log).

**UPDATE:**

If not using the `<<` operator is something that is not a problem for you, you can always use concatenation:

```
LOG(INFO) << QString(connectionsBOther.at(connectionIdx).line
          + " (" + QString::number(connectionsBOther.at(connectionIdx).direction) + ") | "
          + connectionsBOther.at(connectionIdx).directionTarget
          + " "
          + QString::number(connectionsBOther.at(connectionIdx).departureRelative));
```

Comment: I found another solution but yours works too. In order to make the answer complete I added the one I found on my own. :)